# Multiple Scanners in Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream

I just encountered a problem concerning the Scanner(System.in) and threads in Java.

Suppose you have two threads. In both you wait for an user input using the Scanner to read from the System.in input stream. The Problem is that it is not possible to differentiate which string belongs to which thread (the chars will be spread between both strings seemingly random). I suppose this is because the two threads share the same input stream.

Is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: This may be in fact an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask for a specific code solution when the best solution to the overall problem is to use a different approach entirely. Please tell us much more of the background to this problem.

Comment: Have a single class which is responsible for getting input, have this synchronized so that only one thread at a time can request information at a time

Comment: System.in is indeed a shared resource in this case, and must not be accessed from different threads without synchronization. Encapsulate it with a monitor object with synchronized methods

Comment: `Suppose you have two threads. In both you wait for an user input using the Scanner to read from the System.in input stream.` Just don't. There is no sane reason for reading the same stream with two threads.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized block will solve this scanner concerning problem.

```
public class Threader implements Runnable {

    private String name;
    private Scanner input;

    public Threader(String name,Scanner input) {
        this.name = name;
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (input) {
            System.out.print(name + " : " + input.nextLine());
        }
    }

}
```

Pass the scanner object in every new thread.

`Synchronized` means an object having synchronized block does not let two threads to access the code inside the block at the same time. Now we have the critical code inside the block, which means multiple threads won't be able to access the *Scanner object (input)* at the same time.