# How to handle different scanner in different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, synchronized

To avoid an XY Problem, i'm going to explain the context :
I'm doing a chat application in console mode. The user can send a text or a file. If the user receive a file, the console print " New file received ! Where do you want to save it ? : ".

Now the problem :
I have a `while(true)` loop in my `Main.java` where i ask the user what he wants to do, like for example "send" to send a message, or "sessions" to print conversations with users.  So there is a `scanner.nextLine()` in this loop.

I have a thread `listener.java` where i listen about TCP connection, and when i receive a file in TCP, i want to execute a `scanner.nextLine()` to ask the user " Where do you want to save it ? ". 
But i can't do this because my `listener.java` and my `Main.java` interfere, two scanner try to listen from the same stream `( System.in )` at the same time.

I tried the solution indicated here [Multiple Scanners in Multiple Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460771/multiple-scanners-in-multiple-threads) but it don't works. 
I tried to syncrhonize the scanner, but it seems that my thread don't success to lock the scanner.
Same result with Reentrant lock...

I wrote a piece of code to make you understand what i'm saying, it is not my actual code, but it reproduces my problem, a thread who execute sc.nextLine() in the same time with the Main.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    Thread tt = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                //The thread wait...
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            String test= "";
            //Here i receive a file so i ask the user where he wants to save it...
            synchronized (sc) {
                System.out.print("New file received ! where do you want to save it ? ");
                test = sc.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println("File written : " + test);
        }
    });
    tt.start();

    System.out.print("Main blabla ? ");
    String bb = "";
    while(true) {
        synchronized (sc) {
            bb = sc.nextLine();

        }
        System.out.print("blabla : " + bb);
        //Do actions.....
    }
}
```

Comment: Call a method from one thread to notify the other, get the thread that controls the scanner to print. You can do that simply using blocking logic, or more sophisticated async logic. Definitely don't try and share an input stream - you'll very quickly run into issues with buffers.

Comment: But isn't the aim of the "synchronized" keyword to allow multiple threads from access one ressource ? I mean, this is for what it is designed, isn't it ? Why it is not working in this case ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: First and foremost, no - synchronized is to ensure synchronous access to a shared resource; explicitly to disallow concurrent access. But the real reason it doesn't work is because `Scanner` buffers. No amount of magic language keywords will fix that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple `Scanner`s to read from single stream feels brittle. The application would benefit from encapsulating the user interaction functionality in a way the stream and the scanner can not be accessed by other parts of the code base directly. The abstraction should both implement the command loop and handle events incoming from the outside such as receiving the file.

Receiving the events needs to be synchronized appropriately and ideally buffered to a queue so new events can be received while user is responding to previous event. All in all, the user interaction abstraction will be always doing one thing only - reading user response for the next event or next command if there are no events. This was, there will be a single thread and `Scanner` dedicated to read the input stream.